# wx.wizard and python

Tags: python, wxpython

I have a class which derived from wx.frame and need to attach it to wx.wizard as a page
is that possible and if yes how can i do that :

for example i have

frame=myDrevidedFrame(..)

where myDervidedFrame its base class wx.frame

how can i attach the frame object to wx.wizard ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No I dont think you can do that. It wouldnt make any sense to put a `Frame` as a child of a `Dialog`(which is basically what a wx.wizard is).

It shouldn't be too hard to convert your derived frame class to a `PywizardPage`,
basically instead of extending the `wx.Frame` extend the `wx.wizard.PyWizardPage`.

If you haven't already, download the [docs_demos](http://wxpython.org/download.php#binaries) and have a look at the `wx.Wizard` demo for an example of proper usage, it should be enough to get started in the right direction.